# Python, raster plot annotation and plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a raster plot, downloaded from online giving me an image.

```
imshow(data, aspect='equal', extent=(-1, 1, -1, 1), origin='lower')
```

where data is a function to download and retrieve the image.

I want to plot red circles on specific points, `x[918], y[392]` and `x[657], y[740]`. 
I am having trouble plotting these because my graph only extends`-1,1` but the data values within the graph obviously are different.

this is what I've tried so far:

```
plt.plot((data[918,392],data[657,740]),'ro')
annotate('Site 1', xy=data(918,392), xytext=(0,0),
        arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05))
```

Comment: just normalize your points when plotting the annotation or don't use the `extent` kwarg.

Comment: Not sure how to do that, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
plt.imshow(data, aspect='equal', origin='lower')
plt.plot([918,657], [392,740],'ro')
plt.annotate('Site 1', xy=[918,392], xytext=(0,0),
    arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05))
```

There were actually two problems: First, setting `extent=(-1,1,-1,1)` normalized the size of the image. If you omit it, the image keeps its actual pixel size. Second, when plotting the circles you have to provide the coordinates (not the data at the coordinates): `[x1, x2, ...], [y1, y2, ...]`.